# Rails validation context

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, activerecord

I need help with my ActiveRecord model. I have context based validations (mis)using the build-in context options for validations:

```
validates :foo, :on => :bar, :presence => true

model = Model.new
model.foo = nil
model.valid? # => true
model.save # works as expected

model.valid?(:bar) # => false
model.save(:context => :bar) # fails and returns false
```

But using my model in a `accepts_nested_attributes_for :model` and calling `parent.save` fails (the validation gets called and returns false), any suggestions or solutions?

---

Still no answer? To explain more about my problem: I have a model called `Form` which has many `Field`s. Users should see validation errors on submit, but the form should be saved anyway (with and without errors). There are different types of `Field`s, each with global validations (to ensure database consistency) and its own specific user-defined validations (to validate user-entered data). So my `Field`s look someway like that:

```
 # Global validations, to ensure database consistency
 # If this validations fail, the record should not be saved!
 validates_associated :form, :on => :global
 ...

 # Specific user-defined validations
 # If this validations fail, the record should be saved but marked as invalid. (Which is done by a before_save filter btw.)
 def validate
   validations.each do |validation| # Array of `ActiveModel::Validations`, defined by the user and stored in a hash in the database
     validation.new(:on => :specific).validate(self)
   end
 end
```

In my controller:

```
 # def create
 # ...
 form.attributes = params[:form]
 form.save!(:global)
 form.save(:specific)
```

Is something similar possible in Rails using the built-in functionality? Btw this not my actual code, which is quite complicated. But I hope, you guys will get the idea.

Answer (score 8):

Try conditional validations

```
class Customer 
  attr_accessor :managing 

  validates_presence_of :first_name
  validates_presence_of :last_name 

  with_options :unless => :managing do |o|
    o.validates_inclusion_of :city, :in=> ["San Diego","Rochester"]
    o.validates_length_of :biography, :minimum => 100 
  end
end

@customer.managing = true
@customer.attributes = params[:customer]
@customer.save
```

Answer (score 6):

"Ability to specify multiple contexts when defining a validation" was introduced in [Rails 4.1](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_1_release_notes.html) - check [validate method, :on options description](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validate)

Answer (score 3):

**Only for Rails 5+:**

You are looking for

```
with_options on: :custom_event do
  validates :foo, presence: true
  validates :baz, inclusion: { in: ['b', 'c'] }
end
```

To validate or save use

```
model = YourModel.new

# Either
model.valid?(:custom_event)

# Or
model.save(context: :custom_event)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `has_nested_attributes_for :model` to `accepts_nested_attributes_for :models`.

Hope this helps.

Good luck.

Comment: No, sorry for the typo. I meant, of course `accepts_nested_attributes_for`! Thanks btw :)

Comment: I think validation context `:bar` is wrong, but `:on => :create` or `:on => :update` should be fine.