# Nested model validation context

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.9 and I am trying to validate a *nested model* in a specific *context* just for the email attribute *uniqueness*.

In my controller I have:

```
@user.valid? :uniqueness_context
```

In my *nested* model I have:

```
validates :email,
  :format     => {
    :with     => EMAIL_REGEX
  },
  :uniqueness => {
    :on => :uniqueness_context # Here it doesn't work
  },
  :presence   => true
```

**What is wrong? How can I make the above validation code to work?**

---

Notice: if in the model I use the following:

```
validates :email,
  :format     => {
    :with     => EMAIL_REGEX
  },
  :uniqueness => true,
  :presence   => true
```

all works as expected.

---

In order to solve the issue I have tried also to use the following in the model:

```
validates :email,
  :format     => {
    :with     => EMAIL_REGEX
  },
  :presence   => true

validates_uniqueness_of :email, :on => :uniqueness_context
```

but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Where are you getting this `:on => :uniqueness_context` from? It isn't in the docs, and I can't find another case of it being used on the internet.

Comment: @coreyward It is a my custom context and I call it from the controller: `@user.valid? :uniqueness_context`. However I don't know exactly if I am using that in a "good" way.

Comment: Again, where did you learn that this is supported? There's not even an `:on` option for `validates_uniqueness_of`. Are you using a gem or plugin that is supposed to add this functionality?

Comment: @coreyward Ops! You are right: it isn't present in the documentation and maybe it is why it doesn't work... However, I don't know.

Comment: @coreyward - I am not using a gem to accomplish that.

Comment: @coreyward - BTW: On page 245 of "The Rails 3 Way" book there is an example implemented with a custom context.

Comment: @coreyward - No, I am not referring to a scope. If you have the above mentioned book you can read it yourself. The example is in the "Chapter 8: Validation" > "8.4.2 Validation Contexts".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into the same [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032512/rails-validation-context). Seems that Rails currently does not support custom validation contexts. `:if` will do the job for you.

Comment: My problem was, the validations I used were have dependently of the user settings. So grouped related validations into modules, and using a `before_validation` callback, I included only validations which I needed. The result was a clean main class, only including the standard validations I needed, all custom validations are now living in external modules, and are loaded on demand. Do you understand what I'm meaning?

Comment: So and so. If you can make a code example it is sure that I will understand more.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I spaced it for a minute because I didn't realize you could create a custom context.

Looking at the source, it doesn't appear that the UniquenessValidator supports the `:on` context option.

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/validations/uniqueness.rb

Comment: What could be an "hack" to support that?

Comment: You could always just use `:unless` or `:if` to test whether you should validate, and check the context in the method.  It does *seem* like it should work though, as you'd expect `:on => :create` to work, etc.

Comment: I think the difference with Uniqueness is that doesn't make sense with a context — why validate that something is unique only on creation when an update can break it? Custom contexts seem like a bit of a hack in the first place, acting as a sort of weak state machine.

Comment: @coreyward It is because I am planning to use the same email validation methods, for example, for both the user *sign up* (on sign up I create a new user so the email must be unique) and the user *sign in* (on sign in I do not create a new user so I do not need email validation related to uniqueness but I need that for regex and some of similar purposes - That is, on sign in I would like to display to users the errors related to, for example, wrong email format entered as I already make on user sign up).

Comment: 1) Validations aren't run on find. 2) If you are wanting to create a session and validate certain params, those validations should be on your Session, not your User.